# Неправильно работает роут, eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel

Есть 3 роута:

1) /catalog/authors и метод контроллера который просто выводит список всех авторов из бд

2)/catalog/authors/{author} метод контроллера который выводит имя автора если я передаю его айди соответственно.

С этими 2мя я справился, но вот с 3им

3)/catalog/authors/{author}/{book} не получается
Суть в том что я хочу вывести первую книгу заданного автора (одну книгу заданного автора )

Отношения между моделями соответственно:

Автор-Книга 1:М

методы books() и author() соответсвенно.

Маршрут вида 
/catalog/authors/1/1 Работает, НО на /catalog/authors/1/2 Он выдаёт точной такой же результат(тайтл книги к примеру, как и к /catalog/authors/1/1) Хотя 2ая книга автора вообще не задана в БД, постарался объяснить максимально понятно как смог.

Вообще не понимаю нужен ли тут какой то запрос в бд для данное проверки или нет.

Все доки русско и англоязычные уже изучил, но все равно не пойму в чем трабл.
Роуты:

```
Route::get('/catalog/authors', 'AuthorsController@index');
Route::get('/catalog/authors/{author}', 'AuthorsController@show');
Route::get('/catalog/authors/{author}/{book}', 'AuthorsController@display');
```

Контроллер:

```
class AuthorsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $authors = Author::all();

        return view('author.index', compact('authors'));
    }

    public function show(Author $author)
    {
        return view('author.show', compact('author'));
    }

    public function display(Author $author, Book $book)
    {

        return view('author.books', compact('book', 'author'));
    }
}
```

Проблемный вью:

```
@foreach($author->books as $book)
    {{$book->title}}
    @endforeach
```

Модель Автор

```
class Author extends Model
{

    public function books()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Book::class);
    }

}
```

Модель книга

```
class Book extends Model
{
    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Author::class, 'author_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Коды реализации в студию

Comment: Добавил, но он скорее всего неправильный.

Comment: Ваша вьюшка выводит вам все книги автора не учитывая что пришла вам за книга

Comment: На сколько я разобрался, вы хотите что бы `/сatalog/authors/{author}/{book}` выдавал ошибку в случае, если книга не принадлежит автору, иначе не вижу смысла данного роута

Comment: Да, только ошибка должно происходить если идёт роут на айди книги которой нет в бд, у меня же оно прост дублирует первое значение, то есть к примеру: есть первый автор, у которого в бд пока что добавлена только одна его книга, соответственно на роут /catalog/authors/1/1 и должнен выводиться её тайтл, а на/catalog/authors/1/2 должно быть ошибка, у меня же ошибки нет, а просто в /catalog/authors/1/2 дублируется тайтл из /catalog/authors/1/1, хотя в бд 2ой книжки вообще нет.

Comment: Дублируется потому что вы выводите книги автора, и в том и ином случае это одни и те же книги)) А вот на счёт ошибки это вопрос... А вы пробовали книгу выводить? В смысле не книги автора, а именно книгу на вьюшке

Comment: Так у вас фильтрация в зависимости от параметров запроса (url) в каком месте? По моему, вы просто все всегда возвращаете и это же выводите. `return view('author.books', compact('book', 'author'));`

Comment: @OlegShleif тогда результат получается как и метода show обычного.

Comment: @AlexanderBragin ну так какой алгоритм этой проверки(фильтрации)? накодить не проблема, я саму логику не пойму.

Comment: @АлександрХиль https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing, https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-collections, https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent :)

Comment: `/catalog/authors/1/2` какую книгу возвращает? Дебагером пользуетесь?

Comment: @OlegShleif /catalog/authors/1/2 такую же как и /catalog/authors/1/1, хотя её в бд нет, или вы про метод show? Дебагером пользуюсь, но в другом проекте.

Comment: Мне не важно что у вас на вьюхе... Мне нужно именно что приходит в контроллер `/catalog/authors/1/2` под `$book`. Если null (или что-либо иное)  - не стесняйтесь, бросайте исключение в контроллере и вся проблема. (Кстати я не знал что Eloquent так умеет, думал только Doctrine :)

Comment: @OlegShleif а Eager loading тут не нужно применять?

Comment: @OlegShleif http://culttt.com/2014/07/07/doctrine-2-different-eloquent/ и _Eloquent ORM — реализация шаблона проектирования ActiveRecord на PHP. Позволяет строго определить отношения между объектами базы данных. Стандартный для Laravel построитель запросов Fluent поддерживается ядром Eloquent._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать следующие изменения:

В контролере:

```
public function display(Author $author, Book $book)
{
    if (empty($book)) {
         return 'Такой книги нет';
    }
    return view('author.books', compact('book', 'author'));
}
```

В вью:

```
{{$book->title}}
```

В последний параметр роута `/catalog/authors/{author}/{book}` нужно передавать именно id книги (а не номер по порядку). Его можно получить так:

```
$bookId = $author->books()->first()->id;
```